# Using selectors and $(this) in Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have event `mouseenter` link with get ajax request, I want to get selector `$(this)` of link and get attribute. I'm use `context` of setting ajax for AJAX callback.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var request;
  $('a[rel="bookmark"]').mouseenter(function() { 
  // other stuff
  request = $.ajax({
      dataType: "JSON",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
      data: {"action": "our_ajax_function", "id": dataId},
      context: $(this).parent().get(0),
      success: function(data){
          // other stuff
          var gettitle = $(this).attr('data-title').replace('Permanent Link to ','');
      }
  })
});
```

But I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I have event `mouseenter` link with get ajax request, I want to get selector `$(this)` of link and get attribute. I'm use `context` of setting ajax for AJAX callback.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var request;
  $('a[rel="bookmark"]').mouseenter(function() { 
  // other stuff
  request = $.ajax({
      dataType: "JSON",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
      data: {"action": "our_ajax_function", "id": dataId},
      context: $(this).parent().get(0),
      success: function(data){
          // other stuff
          var gettitle = $(this).attr('data-title').replace('Permanent Link to ','');
      }
  })
});
```

But I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>
    <a href="http://localhost/area-no-kishi/" rel="bookmark" data-title="Permanent Link To Area no Kishi" data-id="4126" target="_blank">Area no Kishi </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="http://localhost/aria-the-scarlet-ammo-hidan-no-arai/" rel="bookmark" data-title="Permanent Link To Permanent Link to Aria the Scarlet Ammo ( Hidan No Aria )" data-id="1081" target="_blank">Aria the Scarlet Ammo ( Hidan No Aria ) </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML. Provide a complete example. You get this error because whatever element `$(this).parent().get(0)` refers to, it doesn't have a `data-title` attribute.

Comment: Side note, the good way to access a data attribute is to use `.data('title');`. It will not solve your problem though..

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sure link have `data-title` attribute.

Comment: Yes, but `$(this).parent().get(0)` doesn't refer to the link. And you are setting `this` to `$(this).parent().get(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `this` inside the callback to refer to the `a` element (i.e. the element the handler was bound to), use

```
context: this
```

instead of

```
context: $(this).parent().get(0)
```

`$(this).parent().get(0)` selects the parent of the `a` element, which is a `li` element, which doesn't seem to have a `data-title` attribute.

From the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **context**
>   This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By
>   default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to
>   `$.ajax`). For example, specifying a DOM element as the context will
>   make that the context for the complete callback of a request, like so:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: "test.html",
>   context: document.body
> }).done(function() {
>   $( this ).addClass( "done" );
> });
> ```

---

See also [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394812/this-inside-of-ajax-success-not-working/6394826#6394826)

Answer (score 2):

try assigning "this" to a variable:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var request;
  $('a[rel="bookmark"]').mouseenter(function() { 
  var that=this;
  // other stuff
  request = $.ajax({
      dataType: "JSON",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
      data: {"action": "our_ajax_function", "id": dataId},
      success: function(data){
          // other stuff
          var gettitle = $(that).data('title','Permanent Link to ');
      }
  })
});
```

also while using the **HTML5 Data Attribute** you can get or modify the data in jQuery with the `data()` function:

```
$(that).data('title','Permanent Link to '); //sets the "data-title" of the selected element as "Permanent Link to "
```

Comment: The OP wants to refer to `$(that).parent().get(0)` not the `a` element. Don't see a reason why the OP should "try to assign this to a variable", but maybe you can elaborate on that.

Comment: If you read the problem, OP has access to `this` as an HTML element but the attribute `data-title` is missing.

Comment: @FelixKling  "I want to get selector `$(this)` of link" link means the `a` element, so the OP can pass the element in `that` variable to the ajax call.

Comment: Wouldn't then the better suggestion be to change `context: $(this).parent().get(0),` to `context: this` ? IMO there is not enough information to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon how can the OP access `this` as an HTML element inside another function? and please specify where exactly the OP has mentioned that they can access `this` but not `data-title`?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not saying this is the best way, but this code will definitely work, that's all I'm saying

Comment: Regarding your other comment, you can see that the OP sets `context: $(this).parent().get(0)`. I.e. `this` inside the callback refers to the element `$(this).parent().get(0)`. If that element doesn't have a `data-title` attribute, `attr` will return `undefined`. Your solution is based on the assumption that `this` should refer to the `a` element. This may or may not be the case. The fact that `context: $(this).parent().get(0)` exists in the first place seems to suggest differently.

Comment: @FelixKling you're right, you'll not need context if you wanna do it my way!

Comment: well, thank you all for your time and explanation, amin's solution did resolve my problem, felix's solution too. But as say's felix, If `$(this).parent().get(0)` element doesn't have a `data-title` it will return `undefined`, I think it will help for the future. +1 for both, but sorry amin I accepted felix's answer.

[oot]. I don't know the different with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6456811/1297435).

Comment: @user3612645 it's okay, we're all just here to help, glad you've found your solution ;)